# R, box: How do I use an external package like stats?

Tags: r, r-package, r-box

Suppose `getwd()` yields `"C:/Users/Tom/Documents/Tom_Levers_Git_Repository"`.

In this repository, I have directory `TomLeversRBox`.

In this box, I have module `calculate_probability.R`.

In this module, I have the following function.

```
#' @export
calculate_probability <- function() {
    print(pnorm(1.644854, 0, 1, lower.tail = TRUE))
}
```

In RStudio's console, I run `install.packages("box")`.

I run `box::use(TomLeversRBox/calculate_probability[calculate_probability])` (What does this expression do?).

I run `calculate_probability()`.

I receive the following error.

```
Error in pnorm(1.644854, 0, 1, lower.tail = TRUE) : 
   could not find function "pnorm"
```

How do I use package `stats` within this box, module, or function to allow `pnorm` to be found?

Tangential question: When I change module `calculate_probability.R`, I have to restart my R session. How can I get box to recognize changes to the module file?

Comment: Regarding your tangiential question: there's work ongoing to add [auto-reloading functionality](https://github.com/klmr/box/pull/246) to ‘box’ modules during development. Until then, you can use `box::reload` for module objects, but this won’t work for attached names. To reload attached names, use `box::purge_cache()` and then rerun the `box::use` declaration (this requires the development version of ‘box’, the CRAN version does not yet have this function at the time of writing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As per the FAQ](https://klmr.me/box/articles/faq.html#%E2%80%9Cobject-%E2%80%98lm%E2%80%99-not-found%E2%80%9D-inside-a-module), no core R packages (except ‘base’) are attached inside modules. You’ll need to load (and potentially attach) them explicitly by using e.g.

```
box::use(stats[pnorm])
# or:
# box::use(stats[...])
```

inside the module source code.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are missing is to add `#' @export` before the calculate_probability function in your module.
In the next step you can call the function as `name_of_module$name_of_function` you can read more on how the package works [here](https://klmr.me/box/)

Comment: I added `#' @export`. If I run `box::use(TomLeversRBox/calculate_probability)`, then and only then can I used `calculate_probability$calculate_probability()`. The error remains.